# Combine character vectors in Rcpp

Tags: vector, character, rcpp

I am new to Rcpp and all I want to do is to create a vector by combining two character vectors in Rcpp in the style of:

```
v1 <- c("Cat", "Dog", "Fox)
v2 <- c("Fish", "Python))
res <- c(v1, v2)
```

I know this is basic, but I have already spent over a day going down rabbit holes of pure C++ vector creation, the Rccp CharacterVector style, the endless differences between concatenation of numerics and characters in R vs C++, and a bunch of other, similar things, and I just cannot solve my issue. I have already read through Hadley Wickham's Advanced R guide for Rcpp (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html) and this fairly extensive markdown tutorial (https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/), so please no snarky replies of 'you should really do your research'. Simple, clean examples and any other tips or links or guides would greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't overcomplicate. How would you combine two numeric vectors?  Allocate a new with length n = n1 + n2 and then run two loops over each of the two vectors copying the elements.  Same with vectors of 'strings'.

Comment: Hi Dirk. Thanks for the help. Coming from a pure R background, I has assumed that avoiding loops like the plague was still preferable, rather than the standard C way of doing things, but my benchmarking has proved to me that it is fine time-wise

Comment: Yes. There is a lot of chatter going around that is less than half-informed.